# How to share ssh connections across multiple devices?

Tags: ssh, mobaxterm

I'm using `MobaXterm` and I would like to share my ssh connections across my desktop pc and my laptop, so in this way I don't need to export / import all the ssh connections each time.

So what I tried so far is remove the `MobaXterm.ini` located in the following path: `C:\Users\John\AppData\Roaming\MobaXterm\MobaXterm.ini` and I've copied it within my Google Drive folder which is synchronized through `InSync`.

Then, I've created a symbolic link through the `.ini` stored in Google Drive and the `AppData` folder.

Initially this process seems that has worked well, infact when I've installed `MobaXterm` on my laptop, and repeated the task for the symbolic link, I was able to see all the ssh connections.

The problem's that when I closed and reopened `MobaXterm`, the simbolic link was overwritten by the software, and all the ssh connections was lost ...

Is there any way to keep ssh connections synchronized across my desktop pc and the laptop?

Thanks in advance.